# How to import a spring project in STS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

Just by a mistake I had deleted a spring project in STS.To use it back I borrowed the same project from my friend in zip format but when I tried to import it says

*Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace*

Following is the way I tried to import

file->import->general->existing projects into worspace->select archive file

and after browse when I select the zip project

*Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace*

and the finish button and next button are in disabled state.Please help me

Answer (score 2):

The workspace in STS/Eclipse is not automatically the same as the file structure that you have on disc in your workspace directory. You can have projects in this workspace folder or somewhere else on disc.

To get them into your project explorer (and access them from inside STS/Eclipse), you need to import them (Import Existing Projects into Workspace). Then you can select the folder where those projects are located in. In case you have those projects already in your workspace folder on disc, you can choose the workspace folder as root folder in the wizard. It will show all the projects that exist on disc in that folder and grey those out that are already imported/referenced in your workspace in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is really not in workspace, also if there aren't any other projects with the same name. If not, just delete the `.metadata` folder or create a new workspace.

Comment: I can not delete the workspace because I have some more projects

Comment: And when it comes to project name, keep in mind that the one in `.properties` file is actually important, not the one displayed in the project explorer.

Comment: how can I import all of them,the project is not getting displayed in the project explorere.

Comment: can you tell me if I want to take whole workspace then what I have to do?Shall I take the workspace in zipped format?if yes will I be able to run the projects?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you still have the project in folder of the workspace on disk. You may have deleted in STS, without checking 'Delete on disk'. So, the project may be still there in the workspace folder though its deleted in STS.

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue from time to time. Usually I just open a new workspace but sounds like you don't want to loose other projects.

I simply open the.project file in my project and change the name of the project in name tag.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Probably whey you 'accidentally deleted' your project, you only deleted it from the Eclipse workspace, but not from the actual workspace folder on your hard-drive (as other people pointed out, Eclipse can arbitrarily map workspace projects to files on disk, so it is possible for a project to be 'deleted' from your Eclipse workspace but still exist on disk.

The good news is the files you deleted are actually still there.

Instead of importing your project from a zip, you may just want to import those files from the workspace folder back into your Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this kind of problems not occurred you can go to Project option and clean and than restart STS.
May be STS is not synched with the latest configured project.

Comment: I had this severa times but this problem is not solved

Answer (score 0):

When you launch Spring Tools Suite, it will ask you to **Select directory as workspace** as below:

[image: spring tools suite launcher]

If the directory you selected here (i.e., workspace directory) is the same as the directory where the project that you are going to import resides, then you will get **Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace**.

Therefore, to solve the issue,

- Close Spring Tool Suite
- Create a new directory
- Launch Spring Tool Suite again
- And, select that as your workspace
- Launch the application and you would be able to import as you mentioned in your question

It solved my problem.
Hope it helps..

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score -1):

the problem is that when you delete a project maybe sts only close it.
Try View Menu --> uncheck closed projects
Now you will see all closed project, simply delete it.